# Working with Sails.JS and JsHint

Tags: sails.js, jshint

Assume if I'm working with `Sails.JS` let's call it Sails and using Brackets IDE that implement JsHint as code validator. Is there any best practices how to `validate` Sails's `services` and `models`? Not ignoring them.

Because by default, JsHint force (actually it is help) us to define variable before we use them, even global variable. I don't know why, if I define my `models` like `var model = sails.models.model` or `var Model = global.Model` for example, the application got an error instead.

I want to implement JsHint as neat as possible, because I'm working in team that still don't have any code standard guideline.

Comment: Not really clear what you're asking here.  Is JSHint displaying errors?

Comment: Sorry, already edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check out JShint docs, it will tell you how to define your global variables in an config file or at the top of your script so that it will ignore them.

http://www.jshint.com/docs/

Add to the top of your .js file

```
/*global sails*/
```

Look under the section globals

Comment: I mean I don't want to ignore them, I want to use JsHint as my validator properly, because I working in a team. I wonder, how to initiate `Sails` global variable in each document properly, like JsHint suggested. Because I can't use `var model = sails.models.model` nor `var Model = global.Model`.

Comment: I defined in `package.json`.

Comment: @mattblang how to define in `package.json`?

Comment: Put a property `jshintConfig` with the same configuration options that would be used in the `.jshintrc` file.  For example, [see this snippet](http://pastebin.com/XqxE6waL) that defines `sails` as a global.

Comment: @Meeker Could you bring over the relevant information from the link you provided to the answer itself?  That is generally much better for users who visit a question.

Comment: @mattblang Docs can be changed and updated so I prefer not to lift documentation and paste it here. As the docs do not have direct linking inside, I pointed as close as I could get. Taking your comment into consideration I listed the section a person should look for.

Comment: What about service and model names? they can be expressed as just global variables, but jshint would complain, and I don't want to add a jshingore per each model/controller/service.

Comment: I would suggest using the sails name space and not using your service and model names as globals, but if you still wish to, the comments above show how to put these in your .jshintrc file so you don't have to define them at the top of each file.